# Passing value to a php file via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Let's say that I have two links.

`<li><a href="#" id="VALUE1" class="charName">Name 1</a></li>`

`<li><a href="#" id="VALUE2" class="charName">Name 2</a></li>`

And when I click one of these links jQuery passes the ID of the link I clicked to a PHP file without reloading the page.

*Due to the fact that the id's will not be constants I assume `this.id` will need to be used in the jQuery.*

Then in the PHP file the id is put into a variable then sent to the database. Such as,

```
$var = JQUERY?

insert db...
```

I am just stumped on how to create the jQuery needed to send the ID to the PHP file. And then to retrieve that non-constant ID using PHP.

How might I got about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement some ajax to achieve the same , lets have a click handler for a href first.

And then make a ajax call

```
$('.charName').click(function() {
   var idval = this.id ;

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "id=idval  &location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg ); // this is the response
   }
 });
 return false// this is diable ahref post back to the same page itself
});
```

Comment: Quick question the id=idval just returns idval, how would you format that so it takes the info from the var above... Otherwise, Thank you very much exactly what I wanted.

Comment: im quite sure it should but it seems not to be doing so

Comment: haha i just fixed it by changing data: "id=idval  &location=Boston", to data: {id: this.id}, and removing the var... Once again thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[href=#]").click(function(){


var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));

// ur logic to send id to the db here...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides several ways to send content to the server via Ajax. The one you should look into is the `$.post` method.

The method below will send the id the anchor tag to the server and then alert the servers response. Just make sure that your-file.php is sending a response. Usually I just put something like `echo 'Hi, I like waffles.';` in my php.

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('.charName').bind("click", function(){
      jQuery.post("your-file.php", { id: this.id }, function(response){

         alert(response);
      })
   })
});
```

I like to refer to http://visual.jquery.com whenever I need jQuery help. It's a nice little site.